# How to get docker ip and port in spring boot bootstrap.yml file

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-machine, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to configure the health check for my micro service app in consul which will be running in a docker container.

For configuring the actuator health check to consul, I tried using ${server.address} for host address but it is giving me the docker container id.

Here's the bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      scheme: http
      host: consul.service.consul
      port: 8500
      config:
        format: YAML
        prefix: apps
        data-key: config
        default-context: ${spring.application.name}
      discovery:
        health-check-path: /actuator/health
        healthCheckInterval: 20s
        scheme: http
        enabled: true
        address: ${server.address}
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
```

locally without the docker, it is able to resolve the address correctly but with docker at remote it is returning the container id.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you might face when running inside a Docker container is that when trying to recover the `hostname` or `IP Address`, you will get the internal Docker `hostname` and internal `IP Address`.

A solution that I have used in similar problems, is to:

- Inject the hostname of the Docker Host when creating the container.
- Expose the container port in the Docker Host

For instance:

- Set up the property to take the address from outside:

  ```
  discovery:
     health-check-path: /actuator/health
     healthCheckInterval: 20s
     scheme: http
     enabled: true
     address:${HOSTNAME:server.address}
  ```
- When running your container, provide the value of the `HOSTNAME` property:

  ```
  docker run -e HOSTNAME=myhostname.mydomain.com -p 8500:8500 my_docker_image
  ```

With this, the endpoint you are defining in your service will be accessible for anyone making health checks from outside.

Hope it helps.

Comment: We are actually using marathon for deploying the docker images built through Jenkins pipeline. The host address would change based on the available servers also. Is there any other way to dynamically get the running address and configure consul to point the same?

Comment: I am not familiar with Marathon, but I guess it will provide some way for customizing your containers and provided that variable. As per your Spring Boot service running within the container, there is no way that I know for it to be aware of the host name of the Dcoker Host where it is running.